I want to rollback changes to a commit ID and then commit these rolled back changes as new commit in GIT
I have to be very careful asking this question as I don't want any misunderstandings.
We merged a bunch of PRs into the main branch but we want to remove these merges from it. Reverting one PR after another will consume a lot of time.
Our main branch is protected and I cannot push a version of main branch that is reset to the commit ID I'm trying to rollback to.
Consider my main branch has commit a, commit b... commit f.
Here's what I want to do:

In a new branch, I want to rollback changes to commit c without changing the history of the branch.
I want to commit these changes that have been reset as commit g in the history so it will look like:


commit g
commit f
commit e
commit d
commit c
commit b
commit a


Raise PR with rollback changes without conflicts against main.
Should be able to merge the changes from commit d, e, f in future.

I searched for a lot of reset and revert solutions but none has worked for me so far and I wonder, am I even asking the right question?
Is this possible in GIT?
Am I thinking about this the wrong way? If so, what would be a correct work-around?
A friend of mine suggested this solution (without commands) which confused me more:

just reset to commit, copy a code, rest to head, remove code, copy previous code and push as single commit change and open a PR for this

Any help, appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Does this also help to answer your question?

An answer similar to that, but something that worked out of the box for me is posted below. That worked for me.

Nobody else cares that it worked for you. The important part is why it worked in which context. But whatever, glad your problem is solved, for one thing.

Another option to revert all changes and restore the state of commit c:
from your branch on commit f, run:
# forcefully reset the index (-S) and worktree (-W) to the state in commit [c]:
git restore -SW -s [c] -- .

# commit
git commit


A generic word of caution about git restore -W (short for: git restore --worktree) :
this one of the few destructive git commands -- like git reset --hard -- will happily erase from your disk changes that aren't stored in git, without a way to restore to them.
It is advised to run this command only on a clean worktree. If you have changes, you can either commit them on a different branch, or use git stash to store them in the stash.

Please do not just give instructions, but also describe the idea of what should be achieved by the commands.

@j6t I thought the comment was explicit enough ?

The comment just repeats what the command does. Perhaps what you should add is: "Make a new commit that has the same project state as the commit c. This undoes all changes that happened since then."

THANK YOU! This solved my problem. This is exactly what I wanted to do. Cheers!!!

If I understand you correctly, then git revert is what you're after. From the docs:

Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them.

In other words, git revert f..d will create a new commit (g in your shorthand) that undoes the changes from commits d, e, and f - but those three commits will remain in history, and you can bring them back later if you want.

I get following error:
error: empty commit set passed
fatal: revert failed

Did you provide the actual commit hashes, the relative HEAD~1..HEAD~3, or the literal f..d?

@JimRedmond HEAD~1..HEAD~3 is always an empty set of commits. Did you mean HEAD~3..HEAD~1?

Also, you might want to use -n for the revert, in order to avoid creating a series of new commits, then just commit once at the end of the process.
